# How to create a separate template to output the category in Opencart 2?

Tags: php, content-management-system, opencart

There are several categories of goods in the store on OpenCart 2 and need for one another structure and design. How it can be implemented? Visited options with the creation of the controller and the template output, but does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Can someone come in handy.

In the file **\catalog\controller\product\category.php**

Replace code:

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/category.tpl')) {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/category.tpl', $data));
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/product/category.tpl', $data));
        }
```

To this:

```
$template = 'category.tpl';
        if ($category_id == 72) { $template = 'category-72.tpl'; }

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/'.$template)) {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/'.$template, $data));
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/product/'.$template, $data));
        }
```

Instead of the 72 put your category id.

Creating a template our category here :

**\catalog\view\theme\NAME_THEME\template\product\category-72.tpl**

Then go to **Admin** -> **Modules** -> **Modifiers** and update the cache. Done.

Comment: I think now I understand you, here is a similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755573/specific-template-for-category-and-product-page-in-opencart-2-2-0-0/40763592#40763592

Answer (score 0):

In Opencart 2, `body` has related `class` to page you are viewing, for example if you are in a category, `body` `class` should be:

```
<body class="product-category-20">
```

You can use it like this:

```
body.product-category-20 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

And for another category;

```
body.product-category-21 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

For assign different modules to each category you can add a new layout and then select this layout from design tab, when you edit or create a new category.

Comment: Layout template created in the directory /content/view/theme/myTheme/template/product/nameTemplate.tpl
and in the admin part of the site created a layout in the menu layout, but when connected to the category, no change occurs...
I did everything right?

Comment: No, You don't need to create additional files. Look at this fine article: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=138&t=37119

Comment: Maybe You misunderstood me, I mean for each category its own unique design, that is, I have a design(_layout_) and the need for it to be displayed in that category. Is it possible?

Comment: You need something like this? Category A => assign Module A - Category B => assign Module B

Comment: Not so, for example, category a has the output images of categories and subcategories, and the category B output some text + maybe the goods...