# Specific template for category and product page in OpenCart 2.2.0.0

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am using OpenCart version 2.2.0.0 and trying to set different template for each category and product page. Searching online I found following code:

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/category_' . $category_id . '.tpl')) {
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/category_' . $category_id . '.tpl';
} elseif (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/category.tpl')) {
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/category.tpl';
} else {
    $this->template = 'default/template/product/category.tpl';
}
```

This code works fine for older version of OpenCart but in new version I am not finding similar code structure in catalog/controller/product/category.php file

How can I achieve similar result in OpenCart 2.2.0.0?

Comment: do you use default theme?

Comment: no i am writing a new theme but controller file are in default theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Opencart changed its method from 2.2 that code doesn't work anymore, you can modify it like this:

First we must know which theme is active, store its name in a variable

```
$config_theme = $this->config->get('config_theme') == 'theme_default' ? 'default' : $this->config->get('config_theme');
```

Then we must check if there is a file specially for current category, for example if we are on category 20, we check for category_20.tpl existance.

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $config_theme . '/template/product/category_' . $category_id . '.tpl')) {
```

If found that file:

```
$view = 'product/category_' . $category_id;
```

if there is no such file, use original file: category.tpl

```
} else {
    $view = 'product/category';
}
```

load selected view file based on above statement.

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($view, $data));
```

**conclusion:**

find `$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data));` in `catalog/controller/product/category.php` and replace it with above codes, here is full code:

```
$config_theme = $this->config->get('config_theme') == 'theme_default' ? 'default' : $this->config->get('config_theme');
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $config_theme . '/template/product/category_' . $category_id . '.tpl')) {
    $view = 'product/category_' . $category_id;
} else {
    $view = 'product/category';
}
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($view, $data));
```

Comment: hi thanks it works. can i get the theme name dynamically

Comment: You're welcome, It must recognize your custom theme name, I've tested it both with default and custom theme. but if you have any problem you can use `$config_theme = 'My_Theme';` instead of `$config_theme = $this->config->get('config_theme') == 'theme_default' ? 'default' : $this->config->get('config_theme');`

Comment: ok gr8 is that possible to target sub-category also                                 Again  with bellow code it was possible to add category wise separate style sheet using it bellow before $this->document->setTitle.  `if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/category_' . $category_id .'.css')) { $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/' . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/category_' . $category_id . '.css'); } $this->document->setTitle($category_info['name']); `how can I use this here?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what your looking for?

Comment: hi i could use separate style sheet for each category with this code.how can i use this in current version                                                 `if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/category_' . $category_id .'.css')) { $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/' . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/category_' . $category_id . '.css'); } $this->document->setTitle($category_info['name']); `

Answer (score 0):

I had OpenCart 2.2 designedlike only catalog of goods, index.php had this line:

`$application_config = 'catalog';`

I found here the lines responsible for choosing file of View (MVC technology):

catalog/controller/event/theme.php

My theme dir is 'default2'
Here I change template file for path: /index.php?route=product/category&path=69_65
to file catalog/view/theme/default2/template/product/category_69_65.tpl

The whole code with my snippet is this.

```
<?php
class ControllerEventTheme extends Controller {
    public function index(&$view, &$data) {
        if (!$this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_status')) {
            exit('Error: A theme has not been assigned to this store!');
        }
        
        // This is only here for compatibility with old themes.
        if (substr($view, -4) == '.tpl') {
            $view = substr($view, 0, -4);
        }
        
        if ($this->config->get('config_theme') == 'theme_default') {
            $directory = $this->config->get('theme_default_directory');
        } else {
            $directory = $this->config->get('config_theme');
        }

        if (is_file(DIR_TEMPLATE . $directory . '/template/' . $view . '.tpl')) {
            $view = $directory . '/template/' . $view;
            //my snippet starts
            if ($view=='default2/template/product/category') {
                $url=$data['breadcrumbs'][count($data['breadcrumbs'])-1]['href'];
                if (substr($url, -5)=='69_65') {
                    if (is_file(DIR_TEMPLATE . $directory . '/template/product/category_69_65.tpl')) {
                        $view = $directory . '/template/product/category_69_65';
                    }
                }
            }
        //end of my snippet
        } else {
            $view = 'default/template/' . $view;
        }           
    }
}
```

And this file is that reacts for uri product/catalog  & path=69_65:

catalog/view/theme/default2/template/product/category_69_65.tpl