# template for category page OpenCart 2.2.0.0

Tags: opencart2.x

I would ask for a little help

I would like to create another template for my three categories (category ID 119 / ID 125 / ID 140).

```
I found one solution for version 2.2.0.0.

 find $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data)); 
        in catalog/controller/product/category.php 

        and replace it with above codes, here is:


        $config_theme = $this->config->get('config_theme') == 'theme_default' ? 'default' : $this->config->get('config_theme'); if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $config_theme . '/template/product/category_' . $category_id . '.tpl'))   {
            $view = 'product/category_' . $category_id;
        } else {
            $view = 'product/category';
        }
```

$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($view, $data));

```
I created category_119 however, it does not work. I tried to complete this code but nothing works  

   perhaps I have to complete code by:

         * entering the name of my new template (category_bezkoszyka or category_119) = but I do not know exactly where to sign

        * enter the category ID (119/125/140) = = but I do not know exactly where to sign


        * probably enter the name of my template - although I have default - (Default (Default Store Theme)

Link to the solution:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755573/specific-template-for-category-and-product-page-in-opencart-2-2-0-0/53498989#53498989>


Information:
* opencart 2.2.0.0.
* my new temple category = category_bezkoszyka
* Id category to change = 119 / 125 / 140
* I have a standard theme: Default (Default Store Theme)


How to enter correctly, because I try but it fails.

Thank you for your help

Best Regards. Adam.
```

Comment: What did you try and what did not work? Please be more specific.